# Getting error while checking any one of object has some value using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting error while checking any object has some value from one array using Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

```
let arr = [
    {
      "config": "as",
      "payload": ""
    },
    {
      "config": "as",
      "payload": "xc"
    },
    {
      "config": "",
      "payload": "xc"
    },
    {
      "config": "",
      "payload": ""
    }
]

let isNext = true;

for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i].config !== '' || arr[i].payload !=='') {
     isNext = false
     return;
  }else{
     isNext = true;
  }
}

console.log('next', isNext);
```

Here I have one `array of object` and each object has 2 `key-value pair`. I need inside array it will check if any one of object has some value for both `config` or `payload` then `isNext` will be false other wise it will be true. but as per this code I am getting the following error.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement"`

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: _Is_ that inside a function? If not, what are you trying to return from?

Comment: You are looking for `break`, not return btw

Comment: @Tvde1, sorry my bad it should be break.

Answer (score 1):

Break the loop instead of using return, the return keyword used to return values from methods

[return MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

```
let arr = [
    {
      "config": "as",
      "payload": ""
    },
    {
      "config": "as",
      "payload": "xc"
    },
    {
      "config": "",
      "payload": "xc"
    },
    {
      "config": "",
      "payload": ""
    }
]

let isNext = true;

for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i].config !== '' || arr[i].payload !=='') {
     isNext = false
     break;
  }else{
     isNext = true;
  }
}

console.log('next', isNext);
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't have a `return` statement outside a function scope, if you're trying to escape the for loop use `break` instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is strange because you have no result.
Maybe you want to find the first suitable object from your array?
So the code will be:

```
const arr = [
  {
    "config": "as",
    "payload": ""
  },
  {
    "config": "as",
    "payload": "xc"
  },
  {
    "config": "",
    "payload": "xc"
  },
  {
    "config": "",
    "payload": ""
  }
];

let result = null;
let isNext = true;

for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i].config !== '' || arr[i].payload !=='') {
     isNext = false
     result = arr[i];
     break;
  }else{
     isNext = true;
  }
}

console.log('my result', result);
```

Or you want to check if any of elements are suitable for your condition you can make:

```
const result = arr.some(el => el.config || el.payload);
```

Or you can find and return the first suitable element:

```
const result = arr.find(el => el.config || el.payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code you can replace return from break so it will go out from loop once condition satisfices.

```
for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i].config !== '' || arr[i].payload !=='') {
     isNext = false
     break;
  }else{
     isNext = true;
  }
}
```

use break to step out from loop.